# Product of Gamma functions I

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, products

What is the value of the product of Gamma functions
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{8} \Gamma\left( \frac{k}{8} \right)
\end{align}
and can it be shown that the product
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{16} \Gamma\left( \frac{k}{8} \right) = \frac{ 3 \Gamma(11) \ \pi}{2^{19}} \zeta(2) \zeta(4) \approx \frac{\pi^{7}}{26}
\end{align}
is a valid result?

Comment: This is a simple question of using the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) and the basic property of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$, along with the [known values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) of [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reflection formula $\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ in your case for $z\in \{1/8,2/8,3/8\}$, which only leaves the terms $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$ which are well known, so we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^8 \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{8}\right) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/8)} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/4)} \frac{\pi}{\sin(3\pi/8)} \sqrt{\pi}$$

I don't know if your second equation is valid, but with $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ you can get the left hand side from the initial product, while all the values of $\Gamma$ and $\zeta$ on the right hand side are known, so you can check.

Answer (score 2):

The [multiplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) says
$$\prod_{k=1}^8\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac k8\right)=\prod_{k=0}^7\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac18+\frac k8\right)=(2\pi)^{7/2}\frac{\sqrt8}{8}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(1\right)=4\pi^{7/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can simply calculate:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{8}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^{8}\frac{8}{k}\cdot\frac{k}{8}! = \frac{8^8}{8!}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{8}\frac{k}{8}!$$

Or alternatively (even simpler):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{8}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^{8}\frac{k-8}{8}!$$

---

[image]